# Can grub handle same release (3.6) but new rc (rc5)?

Tags: grub2, kernel

Can grub handle newer kerner rc?
I am running 3.6.0-rc4 ok, grub update definitely recognizes all required files for rc5, but edit of grub.cfg only shows rc4 after `grub-update`.
D/N matter whether I generate kernel 3.6.0-rc5 or whether I install the .deb files.

```
Generating grub.cfg ...
using custom appearance settings
Found background image: /usr/share/peppermint/wallpapers/Peppermint.jpg
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.6.0-030600rc5-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.6.0-030600rc4-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.6.0-030600rc4-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.6.0-rc5
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.6.0-rc5
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.6.0-rc5.old
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.6.0-rc5
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.3
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.3
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.3.old
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.3
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-13-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-13-generic
Found Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS (10.04) on /dev/sda1
Found Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS (10.04) on /dev/sda10
Found Peppermint Two (2) on /dev/sda15
Found Ubuntu 10.10 (10.10) on /dev/sda16
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda3
Found Ubuntu 11.04 (11.04) on /dev/sda5
Found Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (12.04) on /dev/sda6
Found Linux Mint 12 LXDE (12) on /dev/sda8
Found MS-DOS 5.x/6.x/Win3.1 on /dev/sdc1
```

If I press <kbd>e</kbd> on boot startup of rc4 and manually change it to rc5 and ctrl-x, it comes up fine.
I just cannot get grub.cfg to update such that rc4 is included.

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
set default="Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda3)"
if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}

function load_video {
  insmod vbe
  insmod vga
  insmod video_bochs
  insmod video_cirrus
}

insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(hd1,msdos1)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 218e9f6f-c21e-4c50-90a5-5a40be639b66
if loadfont /usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2 ; then
  set gfxmode=640x480
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  insmod part_msdos
  insmod ext2
  set root='(hd1,msdos1)'
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 218e9f6f-c21e-4c50-90a5-5a40be639b66
  set locale_dir=($root)/boot/grub/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ]; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(hd1,msdos1)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 218e9f6f-c21e-4c50-90a5-5a40be639b66
insmod jpeg
if background_image /usr/share/peppermint/wallpapers/Peppermint.jpg; then
  set color_normal=light-gray/black
  set color_highlight=magenta/black
else
  set menu_color_normal=white/black
  set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux_proxy ###
menuentry "Peppermint, with Linux 3.6.0-030600rc4-generic" --class peppermint --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail

    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd1,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 218e9f6f-c21e-4c50-90a5-5a40be639b66
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.6.0-030600rc4-generic root=UUID=218e9f6f-c21e-4c50-90a5-5a40be639b66 ro   
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.6.0-030600rc4-generic
}
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux_proxy ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober_proxy ###
menuentry "Peppermint, with Linux 3.6.0-030600rc4-generic (on /dev/sda15)" --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos15)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 21a3d91a-ae43-4f51-b8d6-7f3dc80967d7
    linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.6.0-030600rc4-generic root=UUID=21a3d91a-ae43-4f51-b8d6-7f3dc80967d7 ro splash quiet splash vt.handoff=7
    initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.6.0-030600rc4-generic
}
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.0.0-24-generic (on /dev/sda10)" --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos10)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6c9a0149-3045-4335-83fa-a2513ca3a250
    linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-24-generic root=UUID=6c9a0149-3045-4335-83fa-a2513ca3a250 ro crashkernel=384M-2G:64M,2G-:128M splash
    initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-24-generic
}
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-030500rc7-generic (on /dev/sda10)" --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos10)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6c9a0149-3045-4335-83fa-a2513ca3a250
    linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-030500rc7-generic root=UUID=6c9a0149-3045-4335-83fa-a2513ca3a250 ro crashkernel=384M-2G:64M,2G-:128M splash
    initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-030500rc7-generic
}
menuentry "Peppermint, with Linux 3.3.0-030300rc2-generic (on /dev/sda15)" --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos15)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 21a3d91a-ae43-4f51-b8d6-7f3dc80967d7
    linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.3.0-030300rc2-generic root=UUID=21a3d91a-ae43-4f51-b8d6-7f3dc80967d7 ro splash quiet splash vt.handoff=7
    initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.3.0-030300rc2-generic
}
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.39-rc5-candela (on /dev/sda16)" --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos16)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 48fcb5ec-b51b-4afd-b0e5-a2aace66f6e1
    linux /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.39-rc5-candela root=/dev/sda7 ro splash
    initrd /boot/initrd.img-2.6.39-rc5-candela
}
menuentry "Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda3)" --class windows --class os {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='(hd0,msdos3)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root EA3EFABB3EFA7FBD
    chainloader +1
}
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.38-13-generic (on /dev/sda5)" --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos5)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root bcfe855e-a449-429d-b204-c667e129a4bd
    linux /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-13-generic root=UUID=bcfe855e-a449-429d-b204-c667e129a4bd ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
    initrd /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-13-generic
}
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-29-generic-pae (on /dev/sda6)" --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos6)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 369605ad-1a92-4b7d-abb5-ce75cbdfc9c1
    linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-29-generic-pae root=UUID=369605ad-1a92-4b7d-abb5-ce75cbdfc9c1 ro quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-29-generic-pae
}
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-23-generic-pae (on /dev/sda6)" --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos6)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 369605ad-1a92-4b7d-abb5-ce75cbdfc9c1
    linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic-pae root=UUID=369605ad-1a92-4b7d-abb5-ce75cbdfc9c1 ro quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-23-generic-pae
}
menuentry "Linux Mint 12 LXDE, 3.0.0-12-generic (/dev/sda8) (on /dev/sda8)" --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos8)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ccdc67ed-e81c-4f85-9b75-fe0c24c65bb8
    linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-12-generic root=UUID=ccdc67ed-e81c-4f85-9b75-fe0c24c65bb8 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
    initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-12-generic
}
menuentry "MS-DOS 5.x/6.x/Win3.1 (on /dev/sdc1)" --class windows --class os {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='(hd2,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root A8F0DE02F0DDD6A2
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober_proxy ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

Answer (score 1):

**[hhoyt](https://askubuntu.com/users/89778/hhoyt)** answered in [edit](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/da5eaa55-9831-4692-b879-8daef1786137/view-source) to question:

> Yes, grub can handle separate RC levels. My problem was I had trashed
>   the kernel levels in question. Using Grub Customizer I was able to
>   recover the trashed kernels and grub now detects them ok. Click on
>   `Trash` then `add entry from trash`.